# Responsive padding/width depending on the content

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have two divs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="text">Text!</div>
</div>
```

The div which has the id "wrapper" needs to have, as its minimum width, the width of its content added a value of 7px. The maximum width would be the width of its content plus 15px. The width of the div which has the id "wrapper" should be responsive when it's not possible to set the max width, but it's possible to set a value in between the minimum and maximum allowed. How would I do it using CSS? (It can be either adjusting padding or width).

I've tried using the flex css property, like:

```
flex: 0 1 10%;
```

It does make the width responsive, but I couldn't define the minimum and maximum values in terms of the width of its content plus the number of pixels.

I've tried using the clamp css function for padding, like:

```
padding-right: clamp(7px, 50%, 15px);
padding-left: clamp(7px, 50%, 15px);
```

But it didn't work. How would I do it using CSS?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you get stuck.

Comment: Added what I've tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo element to simulate the padding and consider flexbox to define their size.

Resize your screen to see how the size of the padding changes:

```css
#wrapper {
  display:inline-flex;
  max-width:100%;
}
#wrapper::before,
#wrapper::after {
  content:"";
  min-width:7px;
  width:15px;
  flex-shrink: 9999; /* to shrink faster than the text*/
  
  background:red; /* to illustrate*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text">some responsive Text here!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I do the same thing without having the responsive text (but having the responsive padding)?

Comment: @Samuel you mean what by *without responsive text*? you don't want wrapping?

Comment: I just want the padding to be responsive. The text content needs to have a fixed width. Only the padding needs to vary. To be clear, considering your example, I want the red part to be as it is, but the part written "some responsive Text here!" should be with fixed width.

Comment: @Samuel add `white-space:nowrap` to #text

Comment: Thank you so much!